# How can I convert a bitmap to pure black and white with OpenCL

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencl, opencl-c, cloo

I've got a WPF - C# project and I'm trying to speed up the image processing I'm doing in there; by doing it using OpenCL and Cloo.

I did manage to get a kernel working that can change a bitmap to grayscale, but for some reason the black and white kernel I've made only outputs a completely black image.

Here's my kernel `.cl` code :

```
kernel void ConvertToBlackAndWhite(read_only image2d_t sourceImage, write_only image2d_t outputImage, float threshold)
{
    const sampler_t mainSampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

    int2 position = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    float4 pixel = read_imagef(sourceImage, mainSampler, position);

    float grayValue = (0.299 * pixel.z) + (0.587 * pixel.y) + (0.114 * pixel.x); // Get Grayscale Value

    const float thresholdValue = threshold * 255.0;

    if (grayValue > thresholdValue)
    {
        const float4 white = (float4){ 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0 }; // #FFFFFF
        write_imagef(outputImage, position, white);
    }
    else
    {
        const float4 black = (float4){ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0 }; // #000000
        write_imagef(outputImage, position, black);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Any help or tips will be appreciated.

I've updated my kernel code based on @ProjectPhysX's helpful advice :

```
kernel void ConvertToBlackAndWhite(read_only image2d_t sourceImage, write_only image2d_t outputImage, float threshold)
{
    const sampler_t mainSampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

    int2 position = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    float4 pixel = read_imagef(sourceImage, mainSampler, position);

    float grayValue = (0.299f * pixel.z) + (0.587f * pixel.y) + (0.114f * pixel.x); // Get Grayscale Value
    if (grayValue > threshold)
    {
        const float4 white = (float4){ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }; // #FFFFFF
        write_imagef(outputImage, position, white);
    }
    else
    {
        const float4 black = (float4){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; // #000000
        write_imagef(outputImage, position, black);
    }
}
```

Here's the C# that adds the images into OpenCL image memory buffers :

```
...

// Allocate OpenCL Image Memory Buffer
inputImage2DBuffer = Cl.CreateImage2D(GPUManipulation.OpenCLContext, MemFlags.CopyHostPtr | MemFlags.ReadOnly, imageFormat,
                                     (IntPtr)width, (IntPtr)height,
                                     (IntPtr)ConstantsMain.Int0, inputByteArray, out error);

...

// Allocate OpenCL image memory buffer
IMem outputImage2DBuffer = Cl.CreateImage2D(GPUManipulation.OpenCLContext, MemFlags.CopyHostPtr | MemFlags.WriteOnly, imageFormat,
                                            (IntPtr)width, (IntPtr)height, (IntPtr)ConstantsMain.Int0, outputByteArray, out error);

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_imagef` returns color/alpha values in the range `[0.0f, 1.0f]` and not `[0.0f, 255.0f]`. This means you have to set:

```c
const float thresholdValue = threshold; // do not multiply by 255.0f here
const float4 white = (float4){ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }; // #FFFFFF
const float4 black = (float4){ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; // #000000
```

The reason everything was black before was that no `grayValue` (in the range `[0.0f, 1.0f]`) could possibly be larger than `thresholdValue` (in the order of `0.5f*255.0f`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice :). You can probably tell; I'm still a rookie. I've updated my kernel code above, but I'm still experiencing the same problem. I'm testing at a threshold of 0.5.

Comment: Which flags do you use in `clCreateImage`? Does conversion from/to `image2d_t` work (if you don't run the kernel, will the output image be the original image)?

Comment: For the input image i think it's `MemFlags.CopyHostPtr | MemFlags.ReadOnly` and for the output image it's `MemFlags.CopyHostPtr | MemFlags.WriteOnly`

Comment: My C# is based off of this post : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502829/GPGPU-image-processing-basics-using-OpenCL-NET

Comment: With flags I meant `Cl.ChannelOrder.RGBA, Cl.ChannelType.Unsigned_Int8`. These should be alright. Try not running the kernel and just the C# part. Is the output image then the same as the inoput image?

Comment: Ok. I've run it with an empty kernel and the result was an all black image. Here's the `.cl` : `kernel void Empty(read_only image2d_t sourceImage, write_only image2d_t outputImage){}`

Comment: I have now got a kernel that works. Instead of `read_imagef`; it uses : `read_imageui` then uses this to convert : `float4 pixelFloat = convert_float4(pixel) / 255.0f;`. I have no idea why that works for me, but the updated kernel above, that uses `read_imagef` doesn't.